# Can I Order By a column name and a case statement at the same time in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am trying to order by query results by 2 things like so

by "reservationStatus" and then by one of two fields depending on the reservationStatus.

this is my mysql code

```
SELECT rs.reservationStatus,
DATE_FORMAT(rs.dateFrom, "%d-%m-%Y %h:%i %p") AS pickupTime,
DATE_FORMAT(rs.dateTo, "%d-%m-%Y %h:%i %p") AS dropoffTime,
cu.fullName,
ve.name FROM reservation AS rs 
INNER JOIN customers AS cu ON rs.CustomerID = cu.customerID
INNER JOIN vehicles AS ve ON rs.Vehicle_id = ve.Vehicles_id
WHERE  rs.dateFrom <= DATE_ADD(curdate() , INTERVAL 86399 SECOND) AND rs.reservationStatus IN (1,2)
ORDER BY  rs.reservationStatus, CASE WHEN rs.reservationStatus = 1 THEN rs.dateFrom ELSE rs.dateTo END ASC
```

That gives me a syntax error. However if I remove rs.reservationStatus,  and leave the case statment there then it runs but i don't see the results ordered like it should.

What i need is to sort my results like this

How can I get my query above to run correctly?

Comment: What syntax error? I don't get one when I run that

Comment: I have no idea! I was getting a syntax error that say check your syntax near line blah blah blah. But I just closed everything and run it again and it worked! I really don't know what happen but it probably something stuck in the cache or some weird like that.  Thanks :)

Comment: So basicly what are you ordering by? This is illogic from my point of view. You have one result set, some records you want to be ordered by something, some by another thing. Order by is used to order the entire recordset. I am not sure why would you ever want to do this at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

"CASE" expressions produce some column result, based on expression derived from other column or columns content. Try rather

```
SELECT 
 column1, 
 CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... AS customcolumnname, 
 column2.sometable, 
 column3 .. 
FROM 
 mytable
ORDER BY 
 customcolumnname ASC, 
 column1 DESC
```

or similar.